# Pessimistic date parsing

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

The javascript Date object parse method is "optimistic", that is, it fills in information that is missing with the earliest possible date.

e.g.

```
new Date('January 2016'); // = Jan 01 2016
new Date('2016');         // = Jan 01 2016
```

I would like a pessimistic parse, which would return the latest possible date for a given input string.

e.g.

```
new Date('January 2016'); // = Jan 31 2016
new Date('2016');         // = Dec 31 2016
```

I will most likely check for the input components manually and fill with max value, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't solve this once the date is constructed. You must known from which string you started. If someone provides a full date of `Jan 01 2016` you don't want to end up with `Jan 31 2016` only because you assumed that since it was the first the date was incomplete. Once you created  a parser to understand the initial unparsed date and identify the missing parts, then it's easy to make the adjustments to the newly created date.

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = {
  "January":31,
  "February":28,
  "March":31,
  "April":30,
  "May":31,
  "June":30,
  "July":31,
  "August":31,
  "September":30,
  "October":31,
  "November":30,
  "December":31
}

var date = new Date(Object.keys(months)[0] + " " 
                   + months["January"] + " " 
                   +  "2016");
```

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: @doublesharp _"What about leap years?"_ Not addressed.

Comment: don't embed hard-coded date info, use a date object to determine the info at boot or run time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I could come up with on the spot. Use one of the functions depending on your date format: Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jzqh561/

```
function convertToPessimisticDate(date) {
    var getMonthPlus1 = parseInt(date.getMonth())+1;
    var getYear = date.getFullYear();
    return new Date(getYear, getMonthPlus1, 0);
}

function convertToPessimisticMonth(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
}
```